# Loading a file that specifies an error form, but getting the error

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, clos, quicklisp, asdf

I'm trying to write a small game in (SBCL) Common Lisp, using Quickload and ASDF to define and manage dependencies. It uses CLOS, so I have a directory in `project` called `classes`, and in there, a file, `locatable.cl`.

The `defclass` form for the LOCATABLE class needs a LOCATOR parameter, so I have a line:

```
:initform (error "Must supply a locator parameter for this class.")
```

Whenever I try to load this file or `quickload` the system, though, I get the error above ("Must supply a locator parameter for this class"). Since I'm trying to define a system and not creating any instances of the class, I don't understand why I'm getting this. If I comment out the error line, everything loads fine, but I was led to believe that the way I have it is a standard way of requiring an `:initval` for a slot.

How do you define such a thing so you can load the file/make a system definition without actually signaling the error?

Here's the class -

```
(defclass locatable ()
  ((zone
    :accessor zone
    :initform nil)
   (locator
    :initarg :locator
    :initform (error "Must supply a locator parameter for this class.")
    :allocation :class
    :accessor locator)))
```

UPDATE: I entered the form at the REPL and got the same error. For curiosity's sake, I entered it in again twice, first with `:initform ""`, then with the error form. It accepted the first form, and didn't complain about the second, so this problem doesn't seem to happen on *re*-definition.

Comment: Something in your system definition must be creating an instance without supplying the proper initialization arguments.

Comment: If that line is by itself, at the toplevel of the file, it is going to evaluate the ERROR form at load time. Can you share the entire DEFCLASS form?

Comment: I've added the class definition to the main question, Xach, thanks. @Barmar, this happens in SLIME even if I only try to load 'locatable.cl', which has no `make-instance` call in it.

Comment: It also seems to be okay when I leave out the `:allocation :class` line. I have no idea if this is because it has to do some kind of test for class-allocated fields, or because of something else.

Comment: I suspect I might have to remove the `initform` and have any field-checking done in an `:after` method of `make-instance`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It seems like the shared slot is being initialized as soon as the class is defined, not when you create the first instance. I reproduced this in CLISP: http://ideone.com/vNCsh2. But I can't find anything in CLHS that supports this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(defclass locatable ()
  ((zone
    :accessor zone
    :initform nil)
   (locator
    :initarg :locator
    :initform (error "Must supply a locator parameter for this class.")
    :allocation :class
    :accessor locator)))
```

The slot `locator` is shared in the class. It will be allocated somehow in the class object. The `DEFCLASS` form creates this class object. Thus the slot `locator` usually will be initialized when the class object is created and initialized. Way before the first instance of that class is created.

**LispWorks Backtrace**

```
CL-USER 50 : 1 > :b
Call to CLOS::CLASS-REDEFINITION-LOCK-DEBUGGER-WRAPPER
Call to INVOKE-DEBUGGER
Call to ERROR
Call to (METHOD CLOS::COMPUTE-CLASS-SLOT-CONSES (STANDARD-CLASS))
Call to (METHOD SHARED-INITIALIZE :AFTER (STANDARD-CLASS T))    ; <--
Call to CLOS::ENSURE-CLASS-USING-CLASS-INTERNAL
Call to (METHOD CLOS:ENSURE-CLASS-USING-CLASS (CLASS T))
Call to CLOS::ENSURE-CLASS-WITHOUT-LOD
Call to LET
Call to LET
Call to EVAL
Call to CAPI::CAPI-TOP-LEVEL-FUNCTION
Call to CAPI::INTERACTIVE-PANE-TOP-LOOP
Call to MP::PROCESS-SG-FUNCTION
```

As you see `SHARED-INITIALIZE` is called on the class object, which then initializes the shared slots.

I also don't think calling `error` like this should be done in user code. You might find a better way to check for missing initargs.

Comment: Thanks. I figure I'll end up using an `:after` method on `initialize-instance`, or an `:initform` that supplies a default.